# Dansguardian Out of Date?

Tags: server

Is Dansguardian still up to date? The last release was in 2009 and there seems to be no active development on it. Are there any major bugs holding it back? MinD web filter http://code.google.com/p/mindwebfilter/ seems promising, but a little on the unstable side. I am looking for a web filter that can handle at least 300 or so users in a school. They currently use squidGuard, which was also last released in 2009.

Answer (score 2):

[Mind Webfilter](http://code.google.com/p/mindwebfilter/) is a good option.

By the way, today they have released the first downloadable package. I'm using Mind webfilter in a small box filtering about 50 users with no issues. I recomend it as a good alternative for Dansguardian.

Comment: Hi. I've just installed Mind-Toy but I can't find the way to run or configure the app. Ther's no manual or tutorial available in its website either... could you help me with that?

Comment: @reyquito: Mind Web Filter has been abandoned and is probably no longer the best choice. Please look at [my answer](//askubuntu.com/questions/40559/dansguardian-out-of-date/626643#626643) instead.

Answer (score 1):

As of May 2015:

DansGuardian itself is no longer maintained.  Nowadays, many websites (such as Google web search and Google image search) are served up over SSL; I don't know how well classic DansGuardian handles SSL filtering.

Mind Web Filter, an old DansGuardian fork, is now an abandoned project.  There have been no commits for years.

The current DansGuardian fork is called "e2guardian".  It's maintained by a different development team, and is still being actively maintained.  The latest release offers an option for SSL filtering.  It's probably a better choice than DansGuardian nowadays.

If anything changes, feel free to edit this post mercilessly (or to leave a comment).

Answer (score 0):

The [website](http://dansguardian.org/) of [dansguardian](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/i386/dansguardian) latest newsitem is from march 2011 (last one before that was 2009 indeed and even worse so is the last update) so it looks dead but seems to be twitching again. Notably from that last message:

> There is a huge backlog of features/bug fixes/etc which have been submitted by people including Smoothwall developers which has not made it to release. We will be getting round to that before we hand over to an integration manager from the DG users community.

The usergroup seems far more active than the developers looking at their [mailing list](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/dansguardian/messages?o=1). Might be an option to have a look and ask questions there.

Answer (score 0):

There's a free web-filtering software called NxFilter.

Main features:

- Active Directory integration
- User or group based policy assignment
- Dual policy for work-time, free-time
- Quota time
- Embedded webserver and embedded DB, built-in GUI
- Blocking by domain category
- Unlimited number of user, group, custom category creation
- Dashboard and reporting
- IP based ACL
- Whitelist and blacklist based on domain matching and keyword searching
- Runs everywhere including Windows, Linux, Mac, FreeBSD.

You can download it from http://www.nxfilter.org

Answer (score 0):

Also you can take a look here, this version fix many problems
http://numsys.eu/search.php?search=Dansguardian